# Replace variable that has float in a string and writing to a new file Python

Tags: python, string, variables

My question is about how to open a file, change a variable in a line.

Example:

`Modelica.SIunits.Height Hfsc = 3.7 "ground floor";`

I need to change the `Hfsc = 3.7` to `Height_1 = 2` and then save the changes in a new file.
It should be something like this:

`Modelica.SIunits.Height Height_1 = 2 "ground floor";`

```
path = '/Users/project.mo'

with open(path, 'r') as f:

    for line in f:

        Height_1 = 2 # defined a variable
        float = 3.7 # do I need to define the 3.7 as a float?

        if "parameter Modelica.SIunits.Height Hfsc" in line:
            str2 = "Hfsc" print(line.find(str2))
            print(line.find('=', 37))
            print(line.find('"', 49))
            indices = [0, 44, 55]
            # indices to identify the splitting position of the string
            parts = [line[i:j] for i, j in zip(indices, indices[1:] [None])

            print(parts)
```

Output:

```
parameter Modelica.SIunits.Height ', 'Hfsc = 3.7 ', '"ground  floor";\n']
```

I can split the line, put I can't replace the variable `Hfsc = 3.7` with `Height_1 = 2` and write a new file.

Comment: you indent is all wrong. fix that otherwise it's not understandable.

Comment: As you describe it, the original line is completely known.  Why don't you just search for an exact match?  And, for complete replacements like this (if my assumption is right), other tools can even be simpler, like, sed.

Comment: @ Dirk Herrmann, it will be better to just replace certain variable in line, as I will have other lines that I know only one identified word in it before the variable.

Comment: Suggest you read [**Should questions include “tags” in their titles?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input is consistent enough, you should be able to simply do this:

```
path = '/Users/project.mo'
newpath = '/Users/project_new.mo'

with open(path, 'r') as fin, open(newpath, 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if "parameter Modelica.SIunits.Height Hfsc = 3.7" in line:
            line = line.replace("Hfsc = 3.7", "Height_1 = 2")

        fout.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, That is really helpful. I will try to apply it for different lines and see how it works. Thanks as well for editing my question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use regular expressions for the substitution and then write to the file. You could then simultaneously open two files, substitute and write to the new file like so:

`import re
to_sub = 'parameter Modelica.SIunits.Height Hfsc = 3.7 "ground floor"'
replacement = 'parameter Modelica.SIunits.Height Height_1 = 2 "ground floor"'
with open(in_path, 'r') as inf, open(out_path, 'w') as outf:
    for line in inf:
        subbed_line = re.sub(to_sub, replacement, line)
        outf.write(subbed_line)`

Hope you found this helpful!

Comment: I find your method helpful, but do you think it will work in this case where I have different csv files that contain hundreds of variables, these variables will be defined in the beginning of the code  as dictionary ex; Height_1=2, Height_2=6 ...etc, and I have a lot of lines that needs to be changed in the txt file.  So I try to find a robust way to easily replace only the variable from the line with the new variables without writing the whole line.

Comment: The reason I suggest regular expressions is that it will allow you to replace a pattern instead of literals as has been done above. This should serve your purpose.